# Reshaping table: Widen table by repeating multiple columns per year

Tags: r, loops, reshape, spread

In order to run a plot code in place, i would like reshape my data.table.

My data table currently looks similar to this:

```
df <- data.frame(culture=c("A","B","C","D","A","B","C","D","A","B","C","D"),
             

Year=c("2000","2000","2000","2000","2001","2001","2001","2001","2002","2002","2002","2002"),
             a=rep(1:6,2),
             b=rep(6:11,2),
             c=rep(10:15,2))
```

The table I would like to get should have the column names a, b and c repeated for each year. Desired columns: culture, a_2000, b_2000, c_2000, a_2001, b_2001, c_2001, a_2002, b_2002, c_2002

Is there a easy way to do this?

I have tried:

```
df1<-df %>% pivot_wider(names_from = c(3:6), values_from = value)

df1<-df %>% spread(key=c(a,b,c), value, fill=NA)

df1<-df %>% nest(a,b,c, .key = 'value_col') %>% spread(key=Jahr, value=value_col) %>% unnest('2000', '2001', '2002', .sep = '_')
```

As you can see from my failed attempts i am not that experienced in r yet.

The last try i got form the suggestion in:https://community.rstudio.com/t/spread-with-multiple-value-columns/5378
This however also didn't work

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a pivot_wider approach:

```
library(tidyr)
df %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = culture, names_from = Year,
              values_from = !c(culture,Year))
# A tibble: 4 x 10
  culture a_2000 a_2001 a_2002 b_2000 b_2001 b_2002 c_2000 c_2001 c_2002
  <chr>    <int>  <int>  <int>  <int>  <int>  <int>  <int>  <int>  <int>
1 A            1      5      3      6     10      8     10     14     12
2 B            2      6      4      7     11      9     11     15     13
3 C            3      1      5      8      6     10     12     10     14
4 D            4      2      6      9      7     11     13     11     15
```

There are other ways you could select the `values_from` columns. Check out `help(tidyr_tidy_select)`.

Also, you can control how the column names are made with `names_glue =` :

```
df %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = culture, names_from = Year,
              values_from = !c(culture,Year),
              names_glue = "Year_{Year}_{.value}")
# A tibble: 4 x 10
  culture Year_2000_a Year_2001_a Year_2002_a Year_2000_b Year_2001_b Year_2002_b Year_2000_c Year_2001_c Year_2002_c
  <chr>         <int>       <int>       <int>       <int>       <int>       <int>       <int>       <int>       <int>
1 A                 1           5           3           6          10           8          10          14          12
2 B                 2           6           4           7          11           9          11          15          13
3 C                 3           1           5           8           6          10          12          10          14
4 D                 4           2           6           9           7          11          13          11          15
```

Comment: This is PERFECT. Thank you very much :)